# Reveal to organisation regarding notice period while candidature in progress

Tags: interviewing, notice-period

I have 7 days left to join an organisation meanwhile I am being interviewed by a second organisation and which might pay well.
Should I tell the second organisation that I have 6-7 days left so they can expedite the progress or I should wait till I am selected and tell them at last moment though that might be risky.
They might be lenient in the process then.
I just want that the organisation with which I am getting interviewed shouldn't get bad impression from my side.

Comment: Hi cbinder and welcome to the Workplace! It's not clear what you are asking in this question, could you edit your question to expand on the situation?

Comment: Why down vote.. while the other person who has answered was able to get it...do ask for clarifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I understand that you have already cleared the interview process of second organization (and had not provided them any information at time of interview that you already have an offer).

I suggest, you should wait for 3-4 days more and HR of second organization might give you a call during the period. At that time you can tell him that you already have an offer in hand. If, your interview went fine and they have urgent requirement, he may provide you a counter/higher offer.

In case, no call comes then call HR to expedite the progress or ask for the offered salary structure.

Also, meanwhile I would also suggest that during the week you should also make up your mind on which organization you would like to join (and don't entirely base it upon salary package)

Comment: Suppose you are working in org. X and have offer from org Y which you are going to join in 7 days. Now, you are getting interviewed by org. Z. Will it be ok that you spend 1 week in org Y (that will fly in induction) and then join org. Z where Y might declare me absconding or blacklist me whatever.

Comment: @cbinder : well, org Y will mark you absconding in there system and probably you will never be able to join Org Y in future. As far as blacklisting going, I have heard that it is effective only if employee is registered with Nasscom etc

Comment: pls upvote my Qn .. it wasn't liable to be downvoted..since your were able to understand the same ;)

Comment: @cbinder : I already up-voted your question when I edited it on Friday. ( actually there were 2 down-votes)